# What is the best way to implement heightmap levels of detail with OpenGL VBOs?

Tags: opengl, buffer, vbo, chunks, heightmap

I'm trying to make infinitely generating terrain, using individual heightmap chunks. For better performance and a higher render distance, I'm trying to implement levels of detail.

I'm using VBOs to store the rendering data for each chunk, but I'm not quite sure how to change between detail levels properly.

If I iterate through my height data every time detail level changes, then I end up with constant VBO updates which really slow down the program. On the other hand, if I try to pre-generate the levels of detail, it's fairly taxing on memory.

In your experience, what's the best way to update the detail levels in this scenario?

Comment: This is an absolutely gigantic topic, so narrowing it down helps a lot: Do you generate your terrain with fractal or other pseudorandom functions? Because if you do you can consider simply moving the computations to the vertex shader, that way you just upload a static mesh and displace it. If you don't: Updating the VBO's is not generally what you want to do as you said, instead you keep track of all LOD data in your RAM and on your disk. You iteratively buffer it from disk to ram and from ram to videomemory, but only when needed. Making the LOD transitions look good is another topic entirely.

Comment: Also, what is the main perspective on the heightmap? birds eye or ground level view with high mountains potentially occluding further distant terrain? Do you zoom through a lot of chunks in a small time or do you only have to update a few chunks a second? To give you a feel of the scope of the topic, see http://vterrain.org/LOD/Papers/ Please update your question with a little more detail.

Comment: As henk said it's a big topic, but for endless terrain I would recommend Geometric Clipmaps or something similar. See here http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter02.html . The very basic concept is that you have a mesh that moves with the viewer. This of course requires you to sample the heightmap in the vertex shader, but the advantage is that LOD is pretty easy, because it just can be coded into the mesh you are  moving.